# Programmatically add new constraint-mappings HV000121: Unable to parse constraint mapping file

Tags: java, xml, validation, bean-validation, pojo

Trying to create a `ValidatorFactory` and programmatically add new constraints to the configuration.

Imagine new `constraint-mappings` files created after initial bootstrap of validation.

But in the unit test below, `ValidatorFactory` is never created due to the error below.

Any idea how the new constraint-mappings files should be loaded?

```
HV000121: Unable to parse constraint mapping file.
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000121: Unable to parse constraint mapping file.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.XmlParserHelper.getSchemaVersion(XmlParserHelper.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.mapping.MappingXmlParser.parse(MappingXmlParser.java:107)

Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:652)
    at java.xml/com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.peek(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.XmlParserHelper.getRootElement(XmlParserHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.XmlParserHelper.getSchemaVersion(XmlParserHelper.java:80)
```

Test:

```
@Test
void test() {

    AnotherPojo anotherPojo = new AnotherPojo();
    assertNoViolations(anotherPojo);
    anotherPojo.setAge(0);
    assertExpectedViolation(anotherPojo, JAVAX_DEFAULT_MIN_MSG_TEMPLATE, "age");
    anotherPojo.setAge(200);
    assertNoViolations(anotherPojo);

    // Create path to additional constraint mappings file
    String fileName = "constraints-xml-pojo-additional.xml";
    File file = new File("src/test/resources");
    String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;
    InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(absolutePath.getBytes());

    // Try create new ValidatorFactory and programmatically add new constraint-mappings
    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
            .configure()
            .addMapping(targetStream) // Passes if this line removed
            .buildValidatorFactory(); <---- Error
    ..
}
```

Directory structure:

```
.
├── main
│   ├── java
│   │   └── com
│   │       └── org
│   │           └── beanvalidation
│   │               ├── SpringBootApplication.java
│   │               └── model
│   │                   └── AnotherPojo.java
│   └── resources
│       └── META-INF
│           ├── validation
│           │   └── constraints-xml-pojo.xml
│           └── validation.xml
└── test
    ├── java
    │   └── com
    │       └── org
    │           └── beanvalidation
    │               └── AnotherPojoTest.java
    └── resources
        └── constraints-xml-pojo-additional.xml
```

`main/resources/META-INF/validation.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<validation-config
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/configuration"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        version="2.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/configuration
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/configuration/validation-configuration-2.0.xsd">

    <constraint-mapping>META-INF/validation/constraints-xml-pojo.xml</constraint-mapping>

</validation-config>
```

`main/resources/META-INF/validation/constraints-xml-pojo.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<constraint-mappings
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/mapping"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/mapping
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/mapping/validation-mapping-2.0.xsd"
        version="2.0">

    <default-package>com.org.beanvalidation.model</default-package>
    <bean class="AnotherPojo" ignore-annotations="true">
        <field name="age">
            <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Min">
                <element name="value">1</element>
            </constraint>
        </field>
    </bean>
</constraint-mappings>
```

`test/resources/constraints-xml-pojo-additional.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<constraint-mappings
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/mapping"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/mapping
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/mapping/validation-mapping-2.0.xsd"
        version="2.0">

    <default-package>com.org.beanvalidation.model</default-package>
    <bean class="AnotherPojo" ignore-annotations="true">
        <field name="age">
            <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Max">
                <element name="value">100</element>
            </constraint>
        </field>
    </bean>
</constraint-mappings>
```

`AnotherPojo.java`:

```
public class AnotherPojo {

    int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems like there's a problem with the way the input stream is created. you are making a stream from bytes that actually are a file path and not the contents of that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to read the XML content into an `InputStream`. Was incorrectly passing the filename instead of the file content.

```
String fileName = "constraints-xml-pojo-additional.xml";
File file = new File("src/test/resources");
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;
Path d = Path.of(new File(absolutePath).getPath());
String content = Files.readString(d, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
InputStream targetStreamDynamic = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(targetStreamDynamic).useDelimiter("\\A");
String result = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

Configuration configuration = Validation
        .byDefaultProvider()
        .configure()
        .addMapping(bufferedInputStream);

configuration.buildValidatorFactory().getValidator();
```